# Django Rest Framework, token authentication: request.user returns AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use Token Authentication from Django Rest Framework.

I followed all the instruction such as:

1.
Adding these lines into installed apps:

```
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
```

2.
Adding statement into settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

I am sending HTTP request with header 'Authorization': 'Token token_name', 
where token_name is token of corresponding user which I can see in a database.

On a server, request.user still returns AnonymousUser and request.user.is_authenticated is False. What can be the issue ?

This is the corresponding view code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

This is corresponding line from urlpatterns:

```
path('test/', views.test)
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your requests?

Comment: @Alex Please provide your corresponding view code...

Comment: Hello,

This is the corresponding view code:
<code>
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    return HttpResponse('ok')
</code>
This is corresponding line from urlpatterns:
    path('test/', views.test),